# How can an Activity get a result from an ActivityResultContract if there is an third intermediate Activity involved?

Tags: android

I am migrating from the old startActivityForResult(Intent) code to the new Activity Result API (using ActivityResultContract).

In the old way of doing things, Activity A can start Activity B, which can in turn start Activity C with

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
```

which will cause Activity B to be deleted from the back stack and for the result to be sent directly to Activity A.  That works, the question is how does achieve the same thing using the new Activity Result API? (I'm using androidx.activity:activity:1.5.1)

Currently, my Activity A does not receive any result from Activity C.

Comment: You are setting that flag on the `Intent` that B uses to start C, right? If so, then the A code should neither know nor care about what's going on. You might consider creating a fresh project that reproduces the problem, then file an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT does still work with the new Activity Result API.  The problem I had is that you cannot also continue to implement the old onActivityResult() method as it will override the new Result API (and return a resultCode of -1).

This means that when migrating an Activity to use the Activity Result API, you must migrate all Intent launches within the Activity, you cannot use both API's at the same time.

Comment: You said you were using th new api. And you were not. Confuding.

Comment: @blackapps - to clarify, my main Activity used two different intents to launch two different Activities (one to cature a photo and a different one to capture a video).  I tried to make one of them use the new API while the other used the old API.  That doesn't work.